# Common Lisp: remove a nested list from a list given a pointer to it

Tags: list, common-lisp

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove a nested list from a list, given a pointer to the nested list. E.g., suppose we say

```
(defvar y '(1 2 3))
(defvar x (list 4 5 y 6 7))
```

Now X is `(4 5 (1 2 3) 6 7)`. Is there a way to use Y to modify X to `(4 5 6 7)`?

```
(setf y nil)
```

doesn't modify X, so it doesn't have the expected effect. The closest I've gotten is

```
(rplacd y nil)
```

which modifies X to `(4 5 (1) 6 7)`.

EDIT: In the problem I am hoping to solve, X is a large and messy (having pointers back into itself in various places). For this reason I would am motivated to try to avoid searching X to find Y and then removing Y. This, I believe, rules out DELETE.

SECOND EDIT: X must be modified in-place. This, too, rules out DELETE, since DELETE might or might not modify X in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete`

```
(setf x (delete y x))
```

While the specification says that `delete` is allowed, but not required, to modify the list in place, it does modify in place in all implementations I'm aware of. However, you still have to assign the result back to the variable to handle some cases:

1. `x` only has 1 element. The result is `NIL`, and this can't be achieved by modifying the list in place.
2. `y` is the first element of `x`. Many implementations of `delete` work by changing the cdr of the previous element, and there's no previous element in this case. So deleting the first element works by returning the second cons.

Comment: Wouldn't just `(delete y x)` do it, too?

Comment: Not if `y` is the first element of `x`.

Comment: and why? in CLISP it is okay - ah I see, in sbcl not.

Comment: In CLISP try: `(defvar x (list 1)) (delete 1 x) (print x)`

Comment: Oh thanks. So always capture the return value of destructive functions and re-assign it - is the rule? So, destructive means just "possibly destructive" ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim "destructive" is not the same as "in-place". A function being defined as destructive simply means there's less guarantees about it (i.e. it's not safe to share structures). It does not mean more guarantees, i.e. that it could be used in-place.

Comment: I think he asks for something different. He would like to change the list, given only a pointer to an item, the 'nested list'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to remove Y without searching X for it (as DELETE must)? In the problem I am hoping to solve, X is a large and messy (having pointers back into itself in various places). For this reason I would am motivated to try to avoid searching X to find Y.

Comment: @RobertDodier No, because to remove it you need a pointer to the previous cons, so you can change its cdr. There's no backward references.

Comment: if this is a problem, you should rethink the data organization.

Comment: Well, the bad news is that this is a data structure in an existing program (Maxima) and reorganizing it would be difficult. Thanks for pointing out the bit about needing access to the preceding cons, I guess the problem cannot be solved as stated.

Comment: Yeah, lists aren't perfect for this kind of thing.